# How to get every first element in 2 dimensional list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have a list like this:

```
a = [[4.0, 4, 4.0], [3.0, 3, 3.6], [3.5, 6, 4.8]]
```

I want an outcome like this (**EVERY** first element in the list):

```
4.0, 3.0, 3.5
```

I tried `a[::1][0]`, but it doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract first item of each sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050311/extract-first-item-of-each-sublist)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can get the index `[0]` from each element in a list comprehension

```
>>> [i[0] for i in a]
[4.0, 3.0, 3.5]
```

Comment: this seems much cleaner than the zip method. Is there any reason not to use this over zip($*rows)?

Comment: a variation with unpacking is `[first for first, *_ in a]`

Answer (score 67):

Use zip:

```
columns = zip(*rows) #transpose rows to columns
print columns[0] #print the first column
#you can also do more with the columns
print columns[1] # or print the second column
columns.append([7,7,7]) #add a new column to the end
backToRows = zip(*columns) # now we are back to rows with a new column
print backToRows
```

You can also use numpy:

```
a = numpy.array(a)
print a[:,0]
```

Edit:
zip object is not subscriptable. It need to be converted to list to access as list:

```
column = list(zip(*row))
```

Comment: in python 3, you need to do list(zip(*rows)), otherwise it is not subscriptable.

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution. Can you please explain a little bit how come zip(*rows) transpose the 2D list?

Answer (score 11):

You could use this:

```
a = ((4.0, 4, 4.0), (3.0, 3, 3.6), (3.5, 6, 4.8))
a = np.array(a)
a[:,0]
returns >>> array([4. , 3. , 3.5])
```

Comment: This should be voted the best answer. Numpy slicing will out perform loops or list comprehensions any day

Answer (score 7):

You can get it like

```
[ x[0] for x in a]
```

which will return a list of the first element of each list in `a`

Answer (score 7):

Compared the 3 methods

1. 2D list: 5.323603868484497 seconds
2. Numpy library : 0.3201274871826172 seconds
3. Zip (Thanks to Joran Beasley) : 0.12395167350769043 seconds

```py
D2_list=[list(range(100))]*100
t1=time.time()
for i in range(10**5):
    for j in range(10):
        b=[k[j] for k in D2_list]
D2_list_time=time.time()-t1

array=np.array(D2_list)
t1=time.time()        
for i in range(10**5):
    for j in range(10):
        b=array[:,j]        
Numpy_time=time.time()-t1

D2_trans = list(zip(*D2_list)) 
t1=time.time()        
for i in range(10**5):
    for j in range(10):
        b=D2_trans[j]
Zip_time=time.time()-t1

print ('2D List:',D2_list_time)
print ('Numpy:',Numpy_time)
print ('Zip:',Zip_time)
```

The Zip method works best.
It was quite useful when I had to do some column wise processes for mapreduce jobs in the cluster servers where numpy was not installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to numpy,

```py
import numpy as np
a_transposed = a.T
# Get first row
print(a_transposed[0])
```

The benefit of this method is that if you want the "second" element in a 2d list, all you have to do now is `a_transposed[1]`. The `a_transposed` object is already computed, so you do not need to recalculate.

## Description

Finding the first element in a 2-D list can be rephrased as find the first column in the 2d list. Because your data structure is `a list of rows`, an easy way of sampling the value at the first index in every row is just by transposing the matrix and sampling the first list.

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
for i in a :
  print(i[0])
```

i represents individual row in a.So,i[0] represnts the 1st element of each row.

Comment: Does not do what is asked.