# Sum array elements vertically with iteration

Tags: python, arrays

Hi I have an array that I want to sum the elements vertically. Just wonder are there any functions can do this easily ?

```
a = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
         [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
         [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

I want to print the answers of `1+6+11+16+21 , 2+7+12+17, 3+8+13, 4+9, 5`
As you can see, in each iteration, there is one element less.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062429/python-how-to-get-every-first-element-in-2-dimensional-list

Comment: You may not really find a pre-built function that does a sum this way because it is fairly "specific" to this problem and not always useful in general. Try *attempting a solution first* and see what you come up with. If you get stuck while attempting a solution, then we can try to help. Show us a *good faith effort*

Comment: There is no specific function for this but you can use `sum(list_comprehension)` for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one approach using `zip` and a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
a = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
         [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
         [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]

print([sum(v[:-i]) if i else sum(v) for i, v in enumerate(zip(*a))])
```

**Output:**

```
[55, 38, 24, 13, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting to a numpy array, and then using the following list comprehension

```
a = np.array(a)
[a[:5-i,i].sum() for i in range(5)]
```

yields the following:

```
[55, 38, 24, 13, 5]
```