# Get the first elements of lists within a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of 21 lists of 10 elements each, I want to get a new list of 21 lists of the 3 elements first elements of the previous ones.

Like if I have `[[1,2],[3,4]]` and I wanted to get `[1,3] (or [[1],[3]])`.

I know how to get this by a loop, but I would like to use a more compact way.

In python we can use `a[:3]` for a simple list for example, but is there anyway to use something like `a[:][:3] (like in MATLAB a(:,1:3))` to get inside the lists in the list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30062429/python-how-to-get-every-first-element-in-2-dimensional-list

Comment: `[i[:3] for i in a]`

Comment: Can you elaborate on *the 3 elements first elements of the previous ones*?

Comment: _I know how to get this by a loop, but I would like to use a more compact way._ Why? How about a list comprehension, does that count as a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
# first 3 items of list in big list    
small_list = [l[:3] for l in big_list]
```

Code:

```
big_list = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"],[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90, 100]]

small_list = [l[:3] for l in big_list]

print (small_list)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [10, 20, 30]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with native Python to acquire a range a elements for each sublist of a list. Apart from list comprehension, the closest you can do is to use [`map`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map):

```
oldList = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"],[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90, 100]]
newList = list(map(lambda l: l[:3], oldList))
```

However, you can download and import the [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) library, which has a syntax that resembles the one that Matlab has:

```
import numpy as np

oldList = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"],[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90, 100]])
newList = big_list[:,0:3]

print(newList)
```

This will return:

```
[['1' '2' '3']
 ['a' 'b' 'c']
 ['10' '20' '30']]
```