# Python List Index Out of Range nested list

Tags: python, list, range

I have a nested list main_category, each nested list is a unicode string of business names. The first five lines of the nested lists are below:

```
[[u'Medical Centers', u'Health and Medical'],
[u'Massage', u'Beauty and Spas'],
[u'Tattoo', u'Beauty and Spas'],
[u'Music & DVDs', u'Books, Mags, Music and Video', u'Shopping'],
[u'Food', u'Coffee & Tea']]
```

So I want to get the first element of every list, and I have tried list comprehension, zip, but nothing works.

```
new_cate = [d[0] for d in main_category]
lst = zip(*main_category)[0]
```

But all of them give me

```
IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-4a397c8e62fd> in <module>()
----> 1 lst = zip(*main_category)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I really don't know what is wrong with this. So could anyone help? Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you verify the code which you execute? copy past from your question works fine for me ['Medical Centers', 'Massage', 'Tattoo', 'Music & DVDs', 'Food'] and ('Medical Centers', 'Massage', 'Tattoo', 'Music & DVDs', 'Food')

Comment: Your full list contains an empty sublist `[]` somewhere. Do confirm that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract first item of each sublist in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050311/extract-first-item-of-each-sublist-in-python)

Comment: To Dashkov, this is just the first five lines of my list, and they should work fine. The problem comes from the rest of them

Comment: To Moses, this full list is very large and I can't really tell where the empty sublist is. If I can't locate this empty sublist, what should I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates one/some of the sublists in the full list are empty lists. You need to properly handle that. You can put a *ternary operator* in the list comprehension to substitute a default value when the list empty is and index the first item when it isn't:

```
default = ''
new_cate = [d[0] if d else default for d in main_category]
#                ^^^^-> test if list is truthy
```

You can also replicate this fix for `zip` by using it's `itertools` variant [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) which allows you to set a `fillvalue`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

default = ''
lst = list(izip_longest(*main_category, fillvalue=default))[0]
```

Comment: That's right. The ternary operator is helping! Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

So you have a list of lists.

```
for content in matrix:
```

At each iteration `content` will return a full list. `[u'Medical Centers', u'Health and Medical']` for example.

If you `print(content[0])`, you will get the first value of the current list, which would be `u'Medical Centers'`.

If there's a list without content in the `matrix`, `print(content[0])` would raise `IndexError`, so you need to check if the current list is not `None` with `if content:`.

---

```
matrix = [[u'Medical Centers', u'Health and Medical'],
[u'Massage', u'Beauty and Spas'],
[u'Tattoo', u'Beauty and Spas'],
[u'Music & DVDs', u'Books, Mags, Music and Video', u'Shopping'],
[u'Food', u'Coffee & Tea']]

for content in matrix:
    if content:
        print(content[0])

>>> Medical Centers
>>> Massage
>>> Tattoo
>>> Music & DVDs
>>> Food
```

Comment: Done. It wouldn't work for @Parker before because I wasn't checking for "empty lists" but I fixed that now.