# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple for list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am getting "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" error while trying to generate list from list of tuples.
list of tuples have the following structure:

```html
[(29208, 8, 8, 8), (29209, 8, 8, 8), (29210, 8, 8, 8), (29211, 8, 8, 8)]
```

The first element in the tuple is a time series, other elements are state of some variables.

The loop for converting from list of tuples to simple list is following:

```html
TimeAxis = []

for n in lst:
    TimeAxis.append(lst[n][0])
```

Where lst has format as described above.
For some reason it throws an error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\Temp\XXX_python_graph\RTT_Plot.py", line 30, in <module>
    Time.append(lst[n][0])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

I understand this is novice question, but other solutions on stackoverflow do not work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TimeAxis.append(lst[0])` or `TimeAxis = [item[0] for item in lst]`

Comment: you use your whole tuple as an index ... that's why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract first item of each sublist in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050311/extract-first-item-of-each-sublist-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's `for` loop is a [*Foreach* construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop); you iterate over the *elements of the list*, not an index.

So `n` is one of the tuples from `lst`, not an index. Use it directly:

```
for n in lst:
    TimeAxis.append(n[0])
```

You could simplify your code by using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
TimeAxis = [tup[0] for tup in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in lst:
    TimeAxis.append(n[0])
```

When you iterate on list, its fetching one by one element, so value of `n` is your every tuple, just access `0th` index of it and append

Answer (score 0):

let me help you understand, what has gone wrong in your code:

```
lst = [(29208, 8, 8, 8), (29209, 8, 8, 8), (29210, 8, 8, 8), (29211, 8, 8, 8)]
for n in lst:  # ns in lst -> (29208, 8, 8, 8), ... , (29211, 8, 8, 8)
    TimeAxis.append(lst[n][0]) # 1st iter: lst[(29208, 8, 8, 8)][0]
```

Hence the `TypeError`. What you probably wanted to do is:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):  # is in range(len(lst)) -> 0,1,2,3 
    TimeAxis.append(lst[n][0])  # 1st iter: lst[0][0]
```

Even though this will work, there is no need for that. There are more pythonic way, which can be found in [@Martijn Pieters answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46275767/8617309).