# Python: Use a Loop to Manipulate Arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have to perform the same operation on a number of arrays. Is there a way to use a loop in Python to carry out this repetitive task?

For example, I have 5 arrays: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`.

I want to carry out the following:

```
A = A[0]
B = B[0]
C = C[0]
D = D[0]
E = E[0]
```

Is there any way to do this using a loop or some other technique to avoid typing almost the same thing multiple times?

My question has been marked as a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050311/extract-first-item-of-each-sublist-in-python). There, the person is asking how to extract the first element from each list (or in my case array). I am not simply trying to extract the first element. I actually want to replace each array with it's first element -- literally `A = A[0]`.

Some are saying this is not a good idea, but this is actually what I want to do. To give some context, I have code that leaves me with a number of 2D arrays, with shapes `n` x `m`. When `n = 1`, the first dimension is irrelevant, and I would like to dispense with that dimension, which is what `A = A[0]` does. My code needs to handle both cases where `n = 1` and cases when `n > 1`.

In other words, when `n = 1`, my code results in an array `A` that is of the following form: `A = array([[a]])`, and I want to change it so that `A = array([a])`. And to reiterate, I need the flexibility of allowing `n > 1`, in which case `A = array([[a1],[a2],...])`. In that case, my code will not execute `A = A[0]`.

The solution by Mark White below works, if you change the last line to:

```
A,B,C,D,E = [x[0] for x in [A,B,C,D,E]]
```

What's interesting is that this solution makes the code more compact, but actually involves as many characters as (an technically more than) the brute force approach.

Comment: This specific task can be done as `A, B, C, D, E = next(zip(A, B, C, D, E))`

Comment: So you want to convert an array to a scalar which equals its first value? I do not think it is a good idea.

Comment: @PaulPanzer In my case, A, B, etc. are arrays. When I try your solution, I get `TypeError: list object is not an iterator`.

Comment: @yann The array is a 2D array. I've provided further context, but this is what I want to do. So, that makes it a good idea.

Comment: @profj Sounds like you are on Python2. You can do `from itertools import izip` and then use `izip` instead of `zip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think it is a pretty easy problem ,in my case ,I use three array ,but I think you can do five , my dear friend!

```
A = [1,3,4]
B = [2,4,5]
C = [54,5,6]
A,B,C = [x[0] for x in [A,B,C]]
```

Comment: I wasn't just trying to extract the values, but replace the A with A[0]. Your solution works if I change the last line to `A,B,C = [x[0] for x in [A,B,C]]`. Thanks.

Comment: @profj I do update answer because of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a list of lists (or, specifically, references to A, B, C, etc.)

```
l = [A, B, C, D, E]
```

Then, you can iterate over `l` however you choose.

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = l[i][0]
```

Note that this will update l[i] rather than the lists (A, B, C, ...) themselves.

Comment: I actually want to update the A, B, C, etc. I don't want to create a new list with their values.