# Append returned variables of a function into different lists

Tags: python, numpy

What is the pythonic way of appending returned variables (More than of one) from a function to different lists?

Suppose we got a function like:

```
def func():
    return np.random.randint(0, 10), np.random.randint(10, 20)
```

The simplest non pythonic way to do it is:

```
l1 = []
l2 = []

for i in range(x):
    # do something
    # do something else
    a, b = func()
    l1.append(a)
    l2.append(b)
```

Or using numpy:

```
lst = []
for i in range(x):
    # do something
    # do something else
    lst.append(func())

l1, l2 = np.array(lst).T
```

Or extracting items using solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050311/extract-first-item-of-each-sublist-in-python).

Comment: Why isn't it 'Pythonic' to use your first solution ? But anyway, using numpy is in most cases, better. Without the need of the Transpose method, you could use the numpy getter [:, 0] or [:, 1] to get an entire ""column"".

Comment: In some situations "Pythonicness" (read: *code golf*) should be sacrificed in favor of readability, maintainability and functionality.

Comment: `test()` should have been `func()`

Comment: @Ravexina, see if the answer posted below helps?

Comment: @DirtyBit Your answer is nice, however it is really similar to one which exists in the link I have mentioned in my question. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to create a `master-list` and then transpose:

```
def func():
    return np.random.randint(0, 10), np.random.randint(10, 20)

masterLst = []    
for i in range(5):
    masterLst.append(func())

l1,l2 = zip(*masterLst)

print(list(l1))
print(list(l2))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[6, 5, 8, 6, 2]
[19, 11, 19, 10, 17]
```

**EDIT**:

Coming in from @hpaulj, a variation to the current approach:

```
def func():
    return np.random.randint(0, 10), np.random.randint(10, 20)

l1,l2 = list(zip(*[func() for _ in range(4)]))

print(list(l1))
print(list(l2))
```

Comment: A variation on your `zip` - list comprehension, and unpacking after list:  `a,b = list(zip(*[fn() for _ in range(4)]))`

Comment: @hpaulj Done! :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the situation, this could be much cleaner:

```
def func(l1, l2):
    l1.append(np.random.randint(0, 10)); l2.append(np.random.randint(10, 20))
    return l1,l2
```