# Extract the n-th element from a list of list of list

Tags: python

I have a list of list of list and I would like to extract the n-th element from each sub-sub list. For example, given the following list:

```
my_list = [[[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[2, 0], [3, 2]], [[2, 0], [3, 3]], [[4, 0], [5, 4]], [[6, 0], [7, 5]]]
```

I want to extract all the first elements keeping the structure of the original list (list of list of list), like:

```
all_first_elements = [[[0],[1]], [[2],[3]], [[2],[3]], [[4],[5]], [[6],[7]]]
```

The problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050311/extract-first-item-of-each-sublist) but with one additional nested list.

I have tried `all_first_elements = [item[0] for item in my_list]` but it returns the first elements of the list of list (and not the first elements of list of list of list).

Comment: `all_first_elements = [[[sub_item[0]] for sub_item in item] for item in my_list]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a double for loop within a list-comprehension

```
all_first_elements = [[[item_1[0]] for item_1 in item_0] for item_0 in my_list]
```

The output will be

```
[[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]], [[6], [7]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function adds a counter to an iterable.

So for each element in a cursor, a tuple is produced with `(counter, element)`.

```
my_list = [[[0, 0], [1, 1]], [[2, 0], [3, 2]], [[2, 0], [3, 3]], [[4, 0], [5, 4]], [[6, 0], [7, 5]]]

for sub_list in my_list:
    for index,elm in enumerate(sub_list):
        sub_list[index] = [elm[0]]

print(my_list)
```

**O/P:**

```
[[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]], [[6], [7]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html), you can slice and index using:

```
import numpy as np

np.array(my_list)[:, :, [0]]
```

[out]

```
array([[[0],
        [1]],

       [[2],
        [3]],

       [[2],
        [3]],

       [[4],
        [5]],

       [[6],
        [7]]])
```

If you need the result as a list, just chain on the [`.tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method:

```
np.array(my_list)[:, :, [0]].tolist()
```

[out]

```
[[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]], [[6], [7]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
all_first_elements = [[[i[0][0]],[i[1][0]]] for i in my_list]
```

**Output** :

```
[[[0], [1]], [[2], [3]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]], [[6], [7]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution that you will not have to update if the nesting level changes:

```py
def extract(data, level, index):
    result = []

    if level == 0:
        return data[index]

    for elem in data:
        result.append(extract(elem, level-1, index))

    return result
```

You will call it like this for the example provided in the original question:

```py
print extract(my_list, level=2, index=0)
```

Please be aware that I have excluded data validation checks for the sake of clarity and because I was not sure how your data may vary. For example, the lists at the n-th level of depth may or may not be empty.