# Making a list from list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the below list of lists

```
[['Afghanistan,2.66171813,7.460143566,0.490880072,52.33952713,0.427010864,-0.106340349,0.261178523'], ['Albania,4.639548302,9.373718262,0.637698293,69.05165863,0.74961102,-0.035140377,0.457737535']]
```

I want to create a new list with only the country names.

So

```
[Afghanistan, Albania]
```

Currently using this code.

```
with open(fileName, "r") as f:
    _= next(f)
    row_lst = f.read().split()
    countryLst = [[i] for i in row_lst]
```

Comment: Try `[sub[0] for sub in row_lst]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract first item of each sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050311/extract-first-item-of-each-sublist)

Comment: The inner lists seem to be made of a single string. Possibly a misplaced quote.

Comment: The sub only prints the first letter of the country 'A'

Comment: It reads in as a string per row, how do I make it not do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using `split(',')` as your first element in `list of list` is `string` separated by `comma`.

```
>>> lst = [['Afghanistan,2.66171813,7.460143566,0.490880072,52.33952713,0.427010864,-0.106340349,0.261178523'], ['Albania,4.639548302,9.373718262,0.637698293,69.05165863,0.74961102,-0.035140377,0.457737535']]
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> [el[0].split(',')[0] for el in lst]                       
['Afghanistan', 'Albania']
```

**Explanation:**

```
# el[0] gives the first element in you list which a string.
# .split(',') returns a list of elements after spliting by `,`
# [0] finally selecting your first element as required.
```

**Edit-1:**

Using `regex`,

```
pattern = r'([a-zA-Z]+)'
new_lst = []
for el in lst:
    new_lst+=re.findall(pattern, el[0])

>>> new_lst     # output          
['Afghanistan', 'Albania']
```

Comment: This worked but when putting split(',') first in the row_lst it gives me an error. Putting the code you shared above under countryLst gave me what I want but I don't think its efficient

Comment: @Electric_Sheep01 *but I don't think its efficient* why? You are not doing any extra steps to achieve results.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a CSV file. Use the `csv` module

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open(fileName, "r") as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   next(reader) #Skip header
   country = [row[0] for row in reader]
```