# Problem loading initial json data to flask-sqlalchemy project: sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying load initial data into a flask-sqlalchemy project from a json file. This is the error that I'm getting.

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (name, twitter, linkedin, youtube, username) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (['Susan Ariel Aaronson'], ['http://twitter.com/AaronsonSusan'], ['https://www.linkedin.com/in/susan-aaronson-b60bb45'], None, ['AaronsonSusan'])]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
```

Here's how I'm trying to load the initial data. I imagine that I'm getting an error because the resulting data is a list and not a string.

```
from app import db
import json

from app.models import User

f = open('data.json')
data = json.loads(f.read())

print([data(**item[0]['username']) for item in data])
```

Here's my model:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    String
)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    twitter = Column(String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    linkedin = Column(String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    youtube = Column(String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    username = Column(String(120), index=True, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.name)
```

I've tried this answer: [Extract first item of each sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050311/extract-first-item-of-each-sublist)

But get a Keyerror:0 error when I try to add something like this: data_first = [item[0] for item in data]

Also, the json data doesn't have an id. Will it load without a primary key?

Comment: You answered you're own question. In some cases, the primary key will auto generate (say, create a new insurance of the User class). In this case, you're uploading data so you should match the structure of the data to your data model.