# get list of 1st elements from table in one line of code [python]

Tags: python

i have a python table like this

```
t = [
  ['a', 1, True],
  ['b', 2, True],
  ['c', 3, True],
  ['d', 4, True]
]
```

i want to extract the 1st element list like this

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

i know how tod do it with a for loop, but i can't do it with one line of code,
i've tried this

```
t[:][0]
```

and also this :

```
t[0][:]
```

but this does not give me what i need

Comment: Read about [list comprehensions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp). Tl;dr: `[v[0] for v in t]`

Comment: List Comprehension will work for this problem you can use the for loop in the same line.

Comment: Also, does this answer your question? [Extract first item of each sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050311/extract-first-item-of-each-sublist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option (and probably the fastest) is a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

```
[ s[0] for s in t ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`list(zip(*t))[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and unpack the list in it:

```
zip(*t)
```

Then convert that to a list:

```
new1=list(zip(*t))
```

This returns

```
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (1, 2, 3, 4), (True, True, True, True)]
```

Now you can simply fetch the first element of the list:

```
print(new1[0])
```